# How do I change values of list all at once?

Tags: python, list, loops

Say I have a list:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to add 1 to each value in the range of indices 0 to 2, so something like this:

```
lst[0:3] += 1
```

However, this is not possible as I get error ***TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable***.

I know I can use the following loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    lst[i] += 1
```

but this takes O(n) time and I wish to do this process all at once, in O(1) time. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: It will always take O(n) time. It cannot be O(1).

Comment: No, this cannot possibly be O(1). It always requires a loop over every element in the list, whether that loop is explicit or not doesn't change the fact that it takes a linear scan through the list, and thus O(N) time... So *even if* this syntax were allowed: `lst[0:3] += 1` it couldn't magically make the underlying solution O(1), it would still be O(N). Just like with numpy array vectorized operations, where `array + 1` does elementwise addition, it can't magically make the underlying operation O(1), it is still O(N)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] but this takes O(n) time and I wish to do this process all at once, in O(1) time. Is it possible to do so?

No. You still need to access all the memory locations of the list's items and update them, there's no way to do that "at once" (meaning, in O(1) time).

---

As per the "how do I do it at all", the loop is the best option you have. Were you using numpy arrays, the syntax `lst[0:3] += 1` would actually work (still in O(n) time, of course), but for lists the `+` operator means concatenation, not addition.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with lists as it doesnot support vectorization.

You can use numpy arrays to do so.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lis = [0,0,0,0]
>>> a = np.array(lis)
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> a[0:3]+=1
>>> a
array([1, 1, 1, 0])
#get that value back into your variable lis
>>> lis = a.tolist()
>>> lis
[1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Because numpy is created for vectorization operations for these and you have to do many tasks like the one specified, go for numpy!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use that syntax you can say

```
    import numpy as np

    your_list = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    your_list += 1
```

but it seems a little overkill to do like that (and still... a for loop would be required, but hidden)